# Shimano thumb shift compatibility

Tags: shifter, compatibility

I need to replace a stiff twist-grip shifter with a thumb shifter to make gear down-changes easier for my wife. There is a choice of two available locally: *Shimano SL-TX50R Tourney* and *Shimano Altus SLM310R7AT*. Are these compatible with a Shimano TX rear derailleur?

Comment: Are they both 7speed versions and does the bike have seven gears? Silly question but I’m getting google results for 6 speed tourney shifters as well as 7speed

Comment: @Swifty I looked em up, both are 7 speed. There are at least three levels of Tourney. *TX* is the higher one and its current iteration is 8 speed, but there are older 7 speed versions, TX50 being one of them I believe.

Comment: @Argenti nice one. One of my hits may have been mis-photoed by a retailer so got me confused

Comment: So meaning an SIS cassette is compatible with a rapidfire shifter right?

Comment: Aside - remember that 6/7/8 speed are all the same "gap" between each cog, so you can use 8 speed shifter on 7 speed cassette fine.  It just leaves an extra click at one end (ideally the smallest cog end)    Great work changing the twist shifter to a normal one, the rider will totally appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a 7 speed rear cassette, any Shimano 7 speed shifter should work.

Shimano's Altus range sits just above the Tourney TX range, so an Altus shifter would nominally be a little better, but matching a TX shifter with a TX derailleur would be fine.

Answer (score 1):

it does not matter. today the Shimano components are mostly compatible with each other. And for a 7-speed derailleur, both of your choices will do the job.

If money doesn't matter, take the higher ranked component, in this case, the Altus shifter.

Comment: "today the Shimano components are mostly compatible with each other." That's certainly not true towards the top of the product line-up, where different ranges have different numbers of rear gears. Here, we're at the bottom of the range, so this apply, but it would probably help to be more specific, here.

Comment: I'd almost say the opposite, sometimes it feels like Shimano go out of their way to make things not compatible (take new tiagra for example that has different pull ratios to all the other 10 speed stuff)

Comment: Thanks everyone for all the great advice, very helpful!
I went with the Altus in the end as it seemed better in every respect. My wife also preferred it as it's the same style as on her previous bike.
I never realised until actually reading the instructions that you can change down 2 gears at a time with it!